# C++'s "inline" - how strong a hint is it for GCC and Clang/LLVM?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, inline-code

In C++, the keyword "inline" serves two purposes. First, it allows a definition to appear in multiple translation units. Second, it's a hint to the compiler that a function should be inlined in the compiled code.

My question: in code generated by GCC and Clang/LLVM, does the keyword "inline" have **any** bearing on whether a function is inlined? If yes, in what situations? Or is the hint completely ignored? Note this is a not a language question, it is a compiler-specific question.

Comment: I agree with @Ashot.  Accept answers to your questions and more people will be willing to take the time to answer this.  As it stands, my answer is more of a guess, and you might need a real "pro" answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I needed to do that, but I will now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Caveat: not a C++/GCC guru] You'll want to read up on [inline here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html).

[Also, this, for GCC/C99.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Hints-implementation.html)

> The extent to which
> suggestions made by using the inline
> function specifier are effective (C99
> 6.7.4).
>
> - GCC will not inline any functions if the -fno-inline option is
>   used or if -O0 is used. Otherwise, GCC
>   may still be unable to inline a
>   function for many reasons; the
>   -Winline option may be used to determine if a function has not been
>   inlined and why not.

So it appears that unless your compiler settings (like `-fno-inline` or `-O0`) are used, the compiler takes the hint.  I can't comment on Clang/LLVM (or GCC really).'

I recommend using `-Winline` if this isn't a code-golf question and you need to know what's going on.

Comment: You should also add, that documentation says this about C99 and according this http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Implementation.html#C_002b_002b-Implementation it is also valid for C++(g++).

Comment: @Ashot thanks.  I'm not super-big on the different standards.  If you're compiling in something other than the latest (C99/GNU99 or whatever) you should know why.

Comment: Notice of link rot: The first link should probably (*probably*) now go to [https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions)

Answer (score 7):

An interesting explanation from [gcc: An Inline Function is As Fast As a Macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html):

> **Some calls cannot be integrated for
>   various reasons (in particular, calls
>   that precede the function's definition
>   cannot be integrated, and neither can
>   recursive calls within the
>   definition)**. If there is a
>   nonintegrated call, then the function
>   is compiled to assembler code as
>   usual. The function must also be
>   compiled as usual if the program
>   refers to its address, because that
>   can't be inlined.
>
> **Note that certain usages in a function
>   definition can make it unsuitable for
>   inline substitution. Among these
>   usages are: use of varargs, use of
>   alloca, use of variable sized data
>   types (see Variable Length), use of
>   computed goto (see Labels as Values),
>   use of nonlocal goto, and nested
>   functions (see Nested Functions).
>   Using -Winline will warn when a
>   function marked inline could not be
>   substituted, and will give the reason
>   for the failure.**
>
> As required by ISO C++, GCC considers
>   member functions defined within the
>   body of a class to be marked inline
>   even if they are not explicitly
>   declared with the inline keyword. You
>   can override this with
>   -fno-default-inline; see Options Controlling C++ Dialect.
>
> GCC does not inline any functions when
>   not optimizing unless you specify the
>   `always_inline' attribute for the
>   function, like this:
>
> ```
>  /* Prototype.  */
>  inline void foo (const char) __attribute__((always_inline)); The remainder of this section is specific
> ```
>
> to GNU C90 inlining.
>
> When an inline function is not static,
>   then the compiler must assume that
>   there may be calls from other source
>   files; since a global symbol can be
>   defined only once in any program, the
>   function must not be defined in the
>   other source files, so the calls
>   therein cannot be integrated.
>   Therefore, a non-static inline
>   function is always compiled on its own
>   in the usual fashion.
>
> **If you specify both inline and extern
>   in the function definition, then the
>   definition is used only for inlining.
>   In no case is the function compiled on
>   its own, not even if you refer to its
>   address explicitly. Such an address
>   becomes an external reference, as if
>   you had only declared the function,
>   and had not defined it.**
>
> This combination of inline and extern
>   has almost the effect of a macro. The
>   way to use it is to put a function
>   definition in a header file with these
>   keywords, and put another copy of the
>   definition (lacking inline and extern)
>   in a library file. The definition in
>   the header file will cause most calls
>   to the function to be inlined. If any
>   uses of the function remain, they will
>   refer to the single copy in the
>   library.

Comment: A question regarding the last bold section: what is the real meaning of "if any uses of the function remain"? In which cases does this happen?

Comment: @el_technic0 Use of a function is calling it or taking its address.

Comment: I still don't understand the difference between "most calls to the function will be inlined" and "any remaining uses of the function will refer to the single copy in the library". Can you give an example of the two different scenarios?

Comment: @el_technic0 I am not sure I could be more clear than that text. Watch Chandler Carruth videos about Clang optimizer.

Comment: Ok, so I guess that the definition in the header is used for inlining, while the source (library) defintion is used for not inlined uses. Still, the fact that there need to be two identical function definitions seems a bit ugly.

Answer (score 7):

A lot of information can be gathered on this by reading GCC and the LLVM project's code. Here is some information that has been gathered by reading the code directly. (Note: this is not necessarily fully comprehensive and this doesn't list every single way in which `inline` affects inlining in every single detail, it's only to give an overview of most of it)

This information was gathered from GCC and and LLVM's current development HEAD as of 2021/11/13, so it might not be up to date in the future.

On GCC's side:

- [GCC will not consider functions not declared `inline` for early-inlining when neither `-finline-small-functions` (implied by `-O2`) and `-finline-functions` (implied by `-O2`) are specified](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/2af63f0f53a12a7275b99d92b271d3dff5112690/gcc/ipa-inline.c#L2899-L2903)
- [GCC will not consider functions not declared `inline` when trying to inline a function optimized for size when the caller isn't and inlining wouldn't shrink the caller](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/2af63f0f53a12a7275b99d92b271d3dff5112690/gcc/ipa-inline.c#L595-L611)
- [GCC's devirtualization time bonus calculations will consider functions declared `inline` to be slightly better unless they are also under the inline function instructions threshold (i.e. `max-inline-insns-auto`, which is explained later) (the code is complicated so I'm being kind of vague here about what exactly it does)](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/2af63f0f53a12a7275b99d92b271d3dff5112690/gcc/ipa-cp.c#L3246-L3248)
- [GCC's inlining use "badness" as a heuristic to determine which edges to inline first. A function declared `inline` will have their "badness" value divided by 8, such that they will be much more likely to be inlined first](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/2af63f0f53a12a7275b99d92b271d3dff5112690/gcc/ipa-inline.c#L1374-L1375)
- [GCC's insns limit (i.e. the "instruction count" heuristic that tries to calculate how many instructions an instruction will take and compare that to the limit) will use a parameter value called `max-inline-insns-auto` in many more cases when the function is not declared inline (although I can see cases where this isn't the case, such as when GCC's heuristics consider that the "speedup seems big", for example): this value is by default 15, whereas the `max-inline-insns-single` value is used when inline is specified, and has a default value of 70, which implies that a function declared inline can be inlined when it is up to 4.6 times bigger than GCC would consider for a function not declared inline](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/2af63f0f53a12a7275b99d92b271d3dff5112690/gcc/ipa-inline.c#L926-L971) (note: the previous hyperlink is only the most important example of those limits being used, they are applied in some other places too)
- [GCC will not split a function if it is not declared `inline` and -finline-small-functions is not specified (implied by -O2)](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/2af63f0f53a12a7275b99d92b271d3dff5112690/gcc/ipa-split.c#L1772-L1780)
- Also note that GCC will normally not investigate inlining non `inline` functions at all without `-finline-functions` (included in `-O2`), unless they are very short, in which case it only just requires `-finline-short-functions` (included in `-O2`)
- There are a few things in the code I wasn't able to fully comprehend but seem to affect inlining in some ways

On LLVM's side:

- [A function declared `inline` will have the `inlinehint` attribute attached to the LLVM bytecode function by Clang](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/54172326e09503e2669fd4ab0f0333f52c387bba/clang/lib/CodeGen/CodeGenModule.cpp#L1875-L1876)
- [When trying to determine the threshold for inlining, it will use the `inlinehint-threshold` value for `inlinehint` functions, which has a default of 325, whereas otherwise it would use other things (such as whether the callsite is hot or cold and other things like that)](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/54172326e09503e2669fd4ab0f0333f52c387bba/llvm/lib/Analysis/InlineCost.cpp#L1838-L1887), and [if nothing else is found, will use the `inlinedefault-threshold` value, which has a default of 225](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/54172326e09503e2669fd4ab0f0333f52c387bba/llvm/lib/Analysis/InlineCost.cpp#L52-L55). This value is compared to a heuristic calculated by LLVM which will calculate for each function call how expensive inlining a given function would be, and if this value is smaller than the threshold, the function will be inlined, which means that inlinehint will essentially diminish the cost of inlining a function by ~1.44 as seen by LLVM
- [When calculating a function's "synthetic entry count", inlinehint will make LLVM use the inline-synthetic-count, which has a default of 15, as the initial value (having a higher count is beneficial to inlining in some form, idk exactly how but it does), whereas it would otherwise use 0](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/54172326e09503e2669fd4ab0f0333f52c387bba/llvm/lib/Transforms/IPO/SyntheticCountsPropagation.cpp#L79-L87)

In other words, it looks like this is quite the strong hint, on both GCC and Clang.

Answer (score 4):

How strong the hint is depends entirely on the compile options you use. Most compilers have options to do no inlining, only inline those marked 'inline', or use its best judgement and ignore the hints.

The last one probably works best. :-)