# Equivalence of static function for methods

Tags: c++, inline, one-definition-rule

Sometimes, I want to have a function in a header file (included in multiple different translation units) without telling the compiler to inline it (for example in a header-only library). This is easy when doing it the C-style way, just declare the function `static`, e.g.:

```
   struct somedata { ... }

   static somefunc (somedata *self) { ... }
```

This lets the compiler decide whether to inline the function or not, while still allowing multiple definitions of the function in multiple translation units, as it has no external linkage. And also allows me to call this function with `somedata` structs created in other translation units, because the types are compatible.

My question is, how do I do this with classes and methods? For example, take this header file, which is practically the same thing using a class and a method instead of a function and an explicit object pointer:

```
   struct someclass {
      void method ();
   }

   void someclass::method () { ... }
```

Obviously, I can't use `static someclass::method` because that is something else entirely.

I also cannot put this into an anonymous namespace, because then I get different `struct someclass` types in different translation units, i.e. I couldn't use a `someclass *` from one file in another, because they would be different (and incompatible) types.

I can declare all these methods `inline`, which would work, but would have the undesirable effect of, well, asking the compiler to inline them even when that makes no sense.

Am I missing something obvious, or does C++ not have the equivalent of `static` for methods? As I see it (hoping to be wrong), the only options for me are to either move all these methods into a separate translation unit or mark them all as inline - there seems to be no equivalent of C-style internal linkage.

**Update:** I think this question was closed prematurely as duplicate. The supposedly duplicate question is about whether marking functions as inline will always inline them. This question is about how to avoid the ODR rule as the static keyword for plain functions does, or explain that this cannot be done in C++, neither of which is answered by the other question, which simply tells the asker to not worry about it. In my question, inline is only mentioned as a possible (but bad) solution.

**Update 2:** It's been mentioned multiple times that inline is nnot a request for function inlining, or that the C standard only uses inline to get around the ODR rule and does not ask the compiler to inline a function.

Both statements are clearly untrue. For example perusing GCC documentation or LLVM source code reveals that widely used compilers do consider `inline` as a request to inline a function. I also quote from C++03, which says (in 7.1.2.2):

[...] The inline specifier indicates to the implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the point of call is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism. [...]

So existing compilers and the C++ standard (I only checked 148882:2003) clearly disagree with the repeated claim of "inline only affects ODR".

This wrong perception seems to be quite widespread, as seen e.g. here: https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/inline-hints/ where somebody investigates this claim by looking at actual GCC/LLVM source code and finds that both compilers treat inline as an actual inlining request.

However, keep in mind that my question is about how to get the effect of `static` for member functions in C++, or alternatively to get a more definitive statement that C++ simply doesn't have this feature for member functions, only for plain functions. The properties of `inline` are only relevant here to the extent that it does solve the problem at the expense of potentially unwanted inlining, which can be bad for performance.

It's relatively clear to me that there is no way around the one definition rule. What is not clear to me is whether there is really no other way to achieve this effect. For example, the next best thing to `static` is an anonymous namespace, but that doesn't work either, as it makes the structs declared in it all incompatible between different translation units, so they can't be interchanged.

I hope there might be a way around it, for example, by having the struct outside the anonymous namespace and having a derived class inside, or some other construct, but I can't see how at the moment, while at the same time I cannot rule out that it might be possible - thus this question.

**Update 3**: To clarify the example - the methods do not contain static variables, and it doesn't matter whether the end result results in multiple physical different copies of a method or not, as long as all such copies behave the same. An actual example of such a method would be:

```
char *reserve (int bytes)
{
  if (left <= bytes)
    flush ();

  if (left <= bytes)
    throw std::runtime_error ("bulkbuf allocation overflow");

  return cur;
}
```

If this method is called often (in the source), but not often (at runtime), asking the compiler to inline it for no reason could be detrimental to performance and certainly to code size.

**Update 4**: There are many repeated claims that compilers universally ignore the inline keyword as a request for inlining, despite good evidence that this is incorrect,.

Just to make get rid of any doubts, I tried it out with this (rather nonsensical) program:

```
//inline
int f(int i)
{   
  return i < 0 ? 0 : f(i-1) + 1;
} 

int main(int argc, char *[])
{   
  return f(5) + f(argc);
}
```

Note the commented out `inline` keyword.

When I compile this with the g++ 6.3.0 (released 2016) from Debian GNU/Linux Stretch (using `g++ -Os -S -o - test.C`), I get this `main` program when `inline` is commented out:

```
    movl    %edi, %ecx
    movl    $5, %edi
    call    f(int)
    movl    %eax, %edx
    movl    %ecx, %edi
    call    f(int)
    addl    %edx, %eax
    ret
```

And this when inline is active in:

```
        xorl    %eax, %eax
.L3:
        cmpl    %eax, %edi
        js      .L2
        incl    %eax
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        addl    $6, %eax
        ret
```

So without `inline` the function did not get inlined, with `inline`, it did get inlined. At the very least, this proves that compilers do not universally ignore inline as a request for inlining, as often claimed (and g++ is certainly one of the few major C++ compilers out there, and version 6.3 is hardly obsolete, so this is not a weird niche compiler).

So fact is, both the standard and existing compilers do treat inline as more than just an ODR behaviour change, namely as an explicit request to inline the function.

Note that whether a compiler ignores the hint or not is only tangentially relevant to my question, which is about the C++ language, not any compilers, and at least C++03 requires compilers to "preferentially" inline functions marked as such, without requiring them to do so, so my concerns with inline are valid whether compilers ignore it or not.

**Update 5:**

Changing `f` to this:

return i < 0 ? 1 : f(i-1) + f(i-2);

results in the analog behaviour with both clang++ 3.8.1-24 and g++. Also, [Do c++11-compatible compilers always ignore inline hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047466/do-c11-compatible-compilers-always-ignore-inline-hints) claims MSVC also heads the inline keyword as request for actual inlining.

g++, clang++/LLVM and MSVC together cover a large share of the C++ "market", so it's safe to say that compilers almost universally treat inline as request for inlining, whether they heed it or not, and in addition to the other requirements from the C++ standard.

Comment: *"asking the compiler to inline"*, wrong, `inline` is just for ODR, inlining of code is done by compiler and is unrelated to mark a function `inline`.

Comment: @Jarod42 uhm, in C++, the inline keyword asks for preferential inline substitution instead of a usual function call, see e.g. ISO 14882:2003 7.1.2.2. Or in non-standardese, marking a function inline asks the compiler to inline it.

Comment: This really seems like an XY problem.  You're trying to do X, think that doing Y will achieve X, but can't work out how to do Y, so you ask for help doing Y.  Problem is, in this case, asking how to do Y doesn't make sense to others.    So try describing what you are ACTUALLY trying to achieve.

Comment: @Peter: Asking to use a method instead of a plain function in C++ _should_ make sense to others, as this is C++. As I have stated, I am trying to use C++ methods in a header-only library, and I already know how to achieve it, albeit with unwanted trade-offs (asking the compiler to inline, or use C functions).

Comment: @MarcLehmann - what doesn't make sense is that you want member functions of a class to have different effects when called from different translation units, based on each of those translation units providing their own local definition.    Member functions of a class are only allowed to have one definition across all translation units that make up a program. Among other things, that means the implementer of a class controls how the various member functions work together, whereas you're trying to allow the user of the class to override that.   Completely the reverse of what happens by design.

Comment: @Peter Why do you think I want that? It's nowhere in my question. What I want is to have the method have the same behaviour in all translation units, without asking the compiler to inline them. Besides, in C++, you _can_ have multiple definitions across translation units just fine (that's what inline gives you, among other things). Lastly, I have no clue what you mean by allowing the user to override things. It seems you are arguing a different question than mine, which asks for a the same effect as static on non-member functions for member functions (or why this cannot be done in C++).

Comment: @Peter In fact, the ability to _have_ multiple definitions across compilation units is an essential feature of C++, as otherwise translation units couldn't share header files defining structs and functions.

Comment: @MarcLehmann - Your understanding is not even close.   If a function in a header file is to be inlined in multiple translation units, the definition must be the same across all translation units - that one definition might be replicated across translation units, so it can be inlined, but there is only one definition.  But if two compilation units get different definitions of such a function, then the behaviour is undefined.   That is true whether the compiler inlines the function or not.

Comment: @Peter there is no need for you to use ad-hominems: I understand how inline functions work and that their definition has to be essentially the same. I am saying it again, even though I said it before: I am not asking for different definitions. I do not. Just believe me when I say I don't. It's not helpful if you keep claiming I ask for different definitions when I really don't.

Comment: @MarcLehmann : your words, first sentence of second para of your question  "This lets the compiler decide whether to inline the function or not, while still allowing multiple definitions of the function in multiple translation units, as it has no external linkage."

Comment: @Peter I think you somehow confuse the word _multiple_ with _different_: In my question I ask for _multiple_ definitions, not multiple _different_ definitions. I really have no idea why you insist on this different thing - I didn't ask it, and by now, have stated multiple times that I don't want different definitions/behaviour, merely multiple ones without inline, or an alternative way to have "static" (in the C sense) member functions. Or an answer stating that C++ can't do it, which I strongly suspect is the case by now.

Comment: @Jarod42 "_inlining of code is done by compiler and is unrelated to mark a function inline_" You CANNOT be serious.

Comment: The ODR has never been a well though out rule, quite the opposite, it's completely undefined, but I think your static function in a header is breaking its intent. It depends on the particular ODR your compiler is using. (And yes, `const int one=1;` is probably illegal in a header file.)

Comment: @curiousguy static functions in header files are very well specified, work basically as they do in C, compilers universally accept it, and there is only one "particular" ODR rule in question in use by compilers, so I am afraid you have to explain a bit more why you think anything regarding static functions behaviour is somehow compiler-specific. Moreover, since static functions are not affected by or named in the ODR rule, it's not clear to me how they can break its intent. Do you say that the ODR rule is supposed to apply to static functions as well?

Comment: I'm not aware that the C language has the equivalent of C++ extern inline functions, template functions, or anything repeated in multiple TU and covered by the ODR the same way. The ODR applies to C++ inline functions. Can inline functions refer to static objects? Not an easy question.

Comment: "_there is only one "particular" ODR rule in question in use by compilers_" which one is it?

Comment: [many compilers offer an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49468469/1505939) to prevent inlining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantics of `static` and `inline` for non-member functions is different even if function definitions are otherwise identical.

```
// in several translation units
static void foo_static() { 
   static int bar; // one copy per translation unit
}

// in several translation units
inline void foo_inline() { 
   static int bar; // one copy in the entire program
}
```

`&foo_static` will also be different across translation units, while `&foo_inline` will be the same.

There's no way to request `static` semantics for member functions (even for *static* member functions).

There is also no way to request `inline` semantics for any function without actually declaring it (explicitly or implicitly) `inline`. In other words, there's no way to say "make this function behave like `inline` in everything except actual inlining".

On the other hand, semantics for function *templates* is similar to that of `inline` functions without a request to the compiler (however meaningless it is nowadays) to inline them at their call sites.

```
// in several translation units
template <nullptr_t=nullptr>
void foo_template() { 
   static int bar; // one copy in the entire program
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question - I am not so much after inline vs. static, but want a generic solution to put methods into header files without having to mark them inline. The idea of using a template is not something I had considered, this might actually be a valid solution, if a bit ugly, as I don't actually need the member functions to be plain functions in most cases except one (a virtual method) - I will investigate this. Thanks!

Comment: As for "&foo_static" will also be different - there seems to be disagreement in the C++ committee about whether this is actually required, and it seems not to be true for existing optimizing compilers (see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3715.html#1400)

Comment: "generic solution to put methods into header files without having to mark them inline". I understood this the first time around. I think I have clearly answered this.

Comment: The standard requires the address to be the same. Implementations are free to do what they want under the as-if rule. Where's the disagreement?

Comment: Functions do not have addresses in the standard (only objects have one, and functions are not objects - the C++ standard does define these words), so it makes no sense to talk about function addresses. The question is whether the function pointers compare equal or not, and the standard contradicts itself here - you have to give functions addresses, drop the equality requirement, or reword it in other ways to fix it.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Making member functions templates is not a satisfactory, and rather heavy handed solution for me, but it's a valid answer, and it seems clear by now that it's the best one can do in C++. Thanks!

Comment: "_Functions do not have addresses in the standard_" since when?

Comment: @MarcLehmann Functions do have addresses. Grep the C++17 standard for "address of a function".

Comment: template functions are implicitly `inline`.

Comment: @Jarod42 that's what I believed too but I cannot find it in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Mark it `inline`.

If you mark the function `static` you'll get a separate copy of that function in every translation unit that includes that header; as a result you'll have multiple copies of that function in your executable. If you mark it `inline` and the compiler doesn't expand it inline you'll get exactly one copy of it in your executable, regardless of how many translation units include that header.