# multiple definitions of an inlined function in 2 or more TU

Tags: c++, inline-functions

I was reading about inline functions and how they could have multiple definitions in different Translation Units but those definitions must be the same.

So what I was thinking is that if I declared in a header file a function and define it in 2 cpp files as inline the compiler will not be angry.

So I tried to do as follow :

**global.h**

```
#ifndef DRAKOS_GLOBAL_H
#define DRAKOS_GLOBAL_H

#include <iostream>
void fct();

#endif //DRAKOS_GLOBAL_H
```

**file1.cpp**

```
#include "global.h"

inline void  fct()
{
    std::cout << "file1.cpp \n";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "global.h"

extern void fct();

int main()
{
    fct();
}
```

Builging ---> Error :

> undefined reference to `fct()'

Ok I looked around in google and I read that

> It’s imperative that the function’s definition be placed in a header
>   file, unless the function is used only in a single .cpp file.

Till now all clear and logic, but the question is, if I put the definition in the header file; every TU will have the same definition, I won't be able to define two versions of the inlined function say one in the file1.cpp TU and the second in the main.cpp TU.

So question 1 : why they say, that for an inline function, could have mutliple definitions in different TU but must be the same (as if I put the definition in the header it will be and couldn't do different in cpp file)

question 2 : If It is possible to do so and define multiple definitions of an inled function (due to miss understanding from my side) could somone plz show me an easy example :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have this inline? Its only going to be defined inside of `file1.cpp`. If you are going to have it inline put it in `global.h`

Comment: it is a matter of test. As I said, the code below has an error and to redomve it I must define the function in the header. the big question is jow to do a multiple definitiln of an inlined function

Comment: Change file1.cpp name to global.cpp, Or include file1.cpp inside your main.

Comment: Your main.cpp does not define the fct(). 
The `extern void fct() ` has no effect since you already include global.h and do not give a body to fct()

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652884/one-definition-rule-multiple-definition-of-inline-functions

Comment: @Paul that is what i was looking for. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code causes undefined behaviour (no diagnostic required) due to rule C++17 [dcl.inline]/6:

> [...]  If a function or variable with external linkage is declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required.

You have `fct` declared inline in `file1.cpp` but not in `main.cpp`.

Also you do not have any definition for `fct` in `main.cpp`. You *could* copy and paste into `main.cpp` (and every other .cpp in the project):

```
inline void  fct()
{
    std::cout << "file1.cpp \n";
}
```

But that would be bad practice because it would be easier to accidentally change one of the functions or forget about a .cpp file. Having it in a header file avoids this problem.