# Why is the inline keyword a hint to inlining?

Tags: c++, inline

Unlike some people still believe, the `inline` keyword in C++ does not primarily exist to tell the compiler to *inline-expand* a function. It exists to tell the linker that there may be multiple definitions of a function and the user promises that all definitions are the same.

But it is *also* related to optimization. People usually say that it is a hint to the compiler to inline a function. I remember I once looked up the inlining metrics in the LLVM source code, and I think it rates a functions inline-value (as in performance gain if the function is inline-expanded) higher if it's declared with the `inline` keyword. Unfortunately I can't find it right now.

Nevertheless I think this is a strange behaviour. The one definition rule and the inline expansion optimization seem totally unrelated to each other. Why is there one keyword that controls both them both (at least to a degree)?

If the compiler knows best when to inline a function, why even take the hint from the `inline` keyword? Is it for historical reasons or does it have any practical value with modern compilers?

Comment: First mentioned purpose (*there may be multiple definitions of a function*) is the way to provide an opportunity for second purpose (*hint to the compiler to inline a function*). You can define inline function in header and include it to multiple compilation units.

Comment: Have you already read https://stackoverflow.com/a/27043088/4944425 ? The second paragraph seems related to your first question.

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, I know the function body needs to be visible during compilation. But the same applies to a `static` function or even an `extern` function that's defined in the same translation unit as one of its callsites. I guess arguably the primary reason to define (non-template) functions in headers is that you want them to be inlined. But another reason could be, that you don't want to require seperate compilation and linking for the one non-template function in your library of templates. Maybe in the end I'm just a bit orthodoxical about leaving low-level optimizations to the compiler.

Comment: Historically, C (and later C++) has always had a separate compilation model so, and `inline` was originally about "inline-expand" which meant (almost) always a need to define such functions in every compilation unit that called it (e.g. in a header).  `inline` was also a hint about "inline-expand" early on because even early compiler/optimisers often did better at deciding that than programmers.  Wording of more recent standards have then evolved to emphasise the use of `inline` with multiple definitions and to deemphasise the "inline-expand" aspect.

Comment: @Peter: And then even more recent standards have moved back somewhat because of modules.